# Filter out invalid geographies in an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, sqlgeography

I'm trying to add a column to a table that contains a lot of geography shapes. The column is going to contain the shape's area. I first altered the table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE geographyShapes ADD shapeArea FLOAT NULL;
```

Then I ran this update statement to fill in the column:

```
UPDATE geographyShapes SET shapeArea = shape.STArea() WHERE shape.STIsValid() = 1
```

I thought this would weed out any invalid shapes, but I guess not because I keep getting this error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
>
> System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
>
> System.ArgumentException: 
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ThrowIfInvalid()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STArea()

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired results using a case statement in the update where clause, but if anyone can tell me why my original update didn't work, I'd still like to know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm spitballing here, but I would guess it's an order of operations thing.  The error is getting thrown when the STArea() function is being run on an invalid geography.  If the function is being applied first, and the results are being filtered second, then this might happen.  What did your query look like when it finally worked?

Comment: This is the query I ended up using: `UPDATE geographyShapes SET shapeArea = CASE WHEN shape.STIsValid() = 1 THEN shape.STArea() ELSE NULL END`

Comment: Your reasoning would make sense, since with the case statement, it forces sql server to apply the STIsValid() first